# Sorting array by multiple prefixes

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array with values. I'm sorting it with a condition to keep certain items at the top. That is working so far. Now I want to run two conditions for example I've two prefixes to be matched with every item in the array: *tableprefix* and *secondaryprefix*. What I have already achieved is keeping *tableprefix* at the top. And the rest of the items must be sorted alphabetically.

**What I want to achieve:**

**1: Array items matching tableprefix at the very top** // already achieved

**2: Array items matching secondaryprefix comes after tableprefix** // can't figure out

**3: Sort rest of the items alphabetically** // already achieved

**Array:**

```
columns = [
   "es_officer_name",
   "es_officer_fname",
   "es_officer_apply_status",
   "es_officer_dob",
   "es_wl_1_11_test_id",
   "es_officer_id",
   "es_designation_id",
   "es_wl_1_11_test_edit_date",
   "es_designation_title",
   "es_employment_type_id",
   "es_employment_type_name",
   "es_service_type_id",
   "es_service_type_name",
   "es_wl_1_11_test_added_date",
   "es_bps_id",
   "es_bps_title",
   "es_department_id",
   "es_department_name"
];
```

**Prefix:**

```
var tablePrefix = "es_wl";
```

**Sorting Algo:**

```
columns.sort(function(a, b) 
{
    if (a.indexOf(tablePrefix))
    {
        if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix)) 
        {
            return a.localeCompare(b);
        } 
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix)) 
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0; // All prefixed are considered equal
        }
    }
});
```

**Sorted Result:**

```
[
  "es_wl_1_11_test_id",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_edit_date",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_added_date",
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_department_id",
  "es_department_name",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_employment_type_name",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_officer_name",
  "es_service_type_id",
  "es_service_type_name"
]
```

**Now what I want is to keep all the items matching the *tablePrefix* `"es_wl"` at the very top. But at the same time Add another prefix *secondaryPrefix* `"es_officer"` so that all matching items would come right after "es_wl" items and then the usual alphabetical sorting.**

I have looked at several items and applied it but the items are not even moving from their place. I guess my logic is completely wrong for integrating second prefix and keeping the first one and sorting afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done here, run the snippet.

```js
var columns = [
  "es_officer_name",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_id",
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_edit_date",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_employment_type_name",
  "es_service_type_id",
  "es_service_type_name",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_added_date",
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_department_id",
  "es_department_name"
];
var tablePrefix = "es_wl";
var secondTablePrefix = "es_officer"
columns.sort((function(firstPattern, SecondPattern) {
  this.sorting = function(a, b, tablePrefix1, primarySort) {
    if (a.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
      if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    } else if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return primarySort ? 0 : a.localeCompare(b); // All prefixed are considered equal
    }
  }
  return function(a, b) {
    var result = sorting(a, b, firstPattern, 1);
    if (result == 0) {
      result = sorting(a, b, SecondPattern, 0);
    }
    return result;
  }
})(tablePrefix, secondTablePrefix));

console.log(columns)
```

**Note:** There is an issue in your sorting code - look at the sorting of `es_officer` it is not alphabetical, I feel even that should be required. It is all done in snippet above.

**UPDATE** :

To get the `id` column in top,

```js
var columns = [
  "es_officer_name",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_edit_date",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_id",
  "es_employment_type_name",
  "es_service_type_id",
  "es_service_type_name",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_added_date",
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_department_id",
  "es_department_name"
];
var tablePrefix = "es_wl";
var secondTablePrefix = "es_officer"
columns.sort((function(firstPattern, SecondPattern) {
  this.sorting = function(a, b, tablePrefix1, primarySort) {
    if (a.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
      if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
        return a.indexOf("_id") != -1 ? -1 : b.indexOf("id") != -1 ? 1 : a.localeCompare(b);
      } else {
        return -1;
      }
    } else if (b.indexOf(tablePrefix1) != -1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return primarySort ? 0 : a.localeCompare(b); // All prefixed are considered equal
    }
  }
  return function(a, b) {
    var result = sorting(a, b, firstPattern, 1);
    if (result == 0) {
      result = sorting(a, b, SecondPattern, 0);
    }
    return result == "retainIt" ? 0 : result;
  }
})(tablePrefix, secondTablePrefix));

console.log(columns)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is sorting both prefixes indeed but it is not doing the third job, sorting rest of the items alphbaticaly

Comment: I am sorry, at first I over looked the rest of the elements. ;)

Comment: I don't know why but for some reason every time i run it the order is getting changed

Comment: In my browser it comes fine and correct order, could you clear cache and try again or open it in incognito and then try. I see correct order, I am running it on chrome for mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126425/discussion-between-a-j-and-wcan).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Make the array into a string, search for the words with the prefixes :

```
var str = columns.toString(); // Array to string
var prefix = "es_wl";
var regex = new RegExp(prefix + "[\\w]+,", "g"); // Word with the prefix
var res = str.match(regex).sort(); // The array with the words that starts with the desired prefix
```

With multiple prefixes, you can put them in an array. Loop through the array, make multiple regexes and [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the sorted array together. After that delete the words in the string with the desired prefixes with [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```
str = str.replace(regex, "");
```

**In total :**

```js
columns = [
  "es_officer_name",
  "es_officer_fname",
  "es_officer_apply_status",
  "es_officer_dob",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_id",
  "es_officer_id",
  "es_designation_id",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_edit_date",
  "es_designation_title",
  "es_employment_type_id",
  "es_employment_type_name",
  "es_service_type_id",
  "es_service_type_name",
  "es_wl_1_11_test_added_date",
  "es_bps_id",
  "es_bps_title",
  "es_department_id",
  "es_department_name"
];

var prefix1 = "es_wl";
var prefix2 = "es_officer";
var prefix3 = "es_department";

var prefixes1 = [prefix1, prefix2];
var prefixes2 = [prefix2, prefix1, prefix3];

function makeCustomOrder(prefixes, arr) {
  var str = columns.toString();
  var res = [];
  prefixes.forEach((pre, i) => {
    var regex = new RegExp(pre + "[\\w]+,", "g");
    res = res.concat(str.match(regex).sort());
    str = str.replace(regex, ""); // Delete the words with the desired prefixes
  });

  res = res.concat(str.split(",").sort()); // Put the sorted rest to the result
  return res;
}

var res = makeCustomOrder(prefixes1, columns);
var res2 = makeCustomOrder(prefixes2, columns);
console.log(res); // Example 1
console.log(res2); // Example 2
```

The **benefit** of the **compact** function `makeCustomOrder()` is that you can use an **array** with **prefixes** **as much as you want**!